# How to enumerate a JSON list of list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, list, nested

I receive the following JSON string from a third party service. (This is the problematic snippet from the JSON string)

```
"last_data_store" : { 
    "02:00:00:00:2a:1a" : 
        { "K" : 1364400231,
          "a" : 4.5,
          "b" : 67,
          "g" : 15634
        },
    "70:ee:50:00:2c:b8" : {
          "'" : 1003.1,
           "K" : 1364400233,
           "S" : 36,
           "a" : 16.199999999999999,
           "b" : 44,
           "e" : 1013.6,
           "g" : 11244,
           "h" : 413
     }
}
```

How do I recursively parse this so that I can extract the key:value pairs ?

I can iterate through each of the two list "objects" in last_data_store using

```
LastDataStore = obj.body.devices[0].last_data_store;
var index = 0;
for (data in LastDataStore) {
console.log(data);
index ++;
}
```

but I only get the MAC Address strings (eg. "02:00:00:00:2a:1a")

If I try something like

```
LastDataStore = obj.body.devices[0].last_data_store;
var index = 0;
for (data in LastDataStore) {
console.log(data.K);
index ++;
}
```

I receive an "undefined" value.

Similarly if I use the following

```
LastDataStore = obj.body.devices[0].last_data_store;
var index = 0;
for (data in LastDataStore) {
console.log(data);
index ++;
      for (foobar in data) {
          console.log(foobar);
      }
}
```

I just get the numbers 0 to 16 which I presume is the number of charcaters in the MAC Address.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LastDataStore = obj.body.devices[0].last_data_store;
for (x in LastDataStore) {
    for (y in LastDataStore[x]) {
        console.log("key: " + y + ", value: " + LastDataStore[x][y])
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hZ7QB/

Comment: This works. Thanks very much. (Now time for much needed zzzz's before wiring up a proper UI)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
LastDataStore = obj.body.devices[0].last_data_store;
var index = 0;
for (data in LastDataStore) {
  console.log(LastDataStore[data]);
  index ++;
}
```

In each of your examples, your `for` loop is returning the key, and you still need to index into your object to get corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't have two lists, you have two objects. Objects are very different from lists. Your `for...in` loop that your using is return the property name (key) not the value which is why `data.K` is undefined.

```
var prop, value;
for (prop in LastDataStore) {
    value = LastDataStore[prop];
    console.log(value.K); // this works now, you've fetched the object with the line above.
}
```

Comment: Your `value` variable is unused.

Comment: @Alan fixed. I knew I was missing something.

Comment: @Alan I am just failing left and right here. I should stop trying to eat and be helpful at the same time.

Comment: @Alan lol :P Too true. I did just get a shirt that says "Eat, Sleep, Code, Game"